# How to loop through dates, 30 times to find historical information at points in time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find out the transaction details of customers at different points in time in the past. I came up with a query but I have to change the date every single time in my declare statement. Is there a way to loop through the dates to get data back x amount of days in the past?

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS Date 
SET @StartDate = '2018-10-30'

SELECT  u.member_id         AS Member_id
    ,CAST(MAX(pe.executed_time) AS Date) AS Max_Date
    ,DATEDIFF(dd,@StartDate,MAX(pe.executed_time))*-1+1 AS R
    ,COUNT(*)               AS F
    ,SUM(pi.Price)          AS M
    FROM [user] AS u
    LEFT JOIN purchase_entry    AS pe
    ON u.member_id=pe.member_id
    LEFT JOIN purchase_item AS pi
    ON pe.order_id=pi.order_id
    WHERE 1=1
        AND pe.[status] = 'purchase'
        AND pe.executed_time <= @StartDate -- Change the declared Date to have historical information.
    GROUP BY u.id, u.member_id
    ORDER BY Recency
```

I need a way to have my query to loop through the @StartDate for 30 days in the past for instance. For ex: @StartDate = '2018-11-30' then @StartDate '2018-11-29' , and so on ...

Comment: could you put together a sample data and expected output for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the dates that you want:

```
WITH dates as (
      SELECT v.*
      FROM (VALUES (CONVERT(DATE, '2018-11-30')), (CONVERT(DATE, '2018-11-29'))
         ) v(dte)
     )
SELECT dates.dte, u.member_id, . . .
FROM dates CROSS JOIN
     [user] u JOIN
     purchase_entry pe
     ON u.member_id = pe.member_id LEFT JOIN
     purchase_item pi
     ON pe.order_id = pi.order_id
WHERE pe.[status] = 'purchase' AND
      pe.executed_time <= date.dte -- Change the declared Date to have historical information.
GROUP BY v.dte, u.id, u.member_id
ORDER BY Recency;
```

For a specific period of dates, you can construct them using a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select convert(date, '2018-11-30') as dte, 1 as n
      union all
      select dateadd(day, -1, date.dte), n + 1
      from dates
      where n < 30
     )
. . .
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a tally table to generate the date and then query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS Date 
SET @StartDate = '2018-10-30'
WITH N AS (
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP 30 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1
         CROSS JOIN N N2
         CROSS JOIN N N3),
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, I, @StartDate) AS [Date]
    FROM Tally
)
SELECT  u.member_id         AS Member_id
    ,CAST(MAX(pe.executed_time) AS Date) AS Max_Date
    ,DATEDIFF(dd,@StartDate,MAX(pe.executed_time))*-1+1 AS R
    ,COUNT(*)               AS F
    ,SUM(pi.Price)          AS M
    FROM [user] AS u
         CROSS JOIN Dates D
    LEFT JOIN purchase_entry    AS pe
    ON u.member_id=pe.member_id
    LEFT JOIN purchase_item AS pi
    ON pe.order_id=pi.order_id
    WHERE pe.[status] = 'purchase'
      AND pe.executed_time <= D.[Date]
    ORDER BY Recency;
```